# Can I sync my save games between 3DS and Wii U?

Tags: shantae-pirates-curse

*Shantae and the Pirate's Curse* is finally available in my region, and having greatly enjoyed *Shantae: Risky's Revenge* on DSi, I obviously want to buy the sequel; only it's available on both 3DS and Wii U, and I'm not quite certain which version I'd like to buy.

Before I decide, I'd like to know if both versions can synchronize their save games. If they can, I could just buy *both* and stop worrying about which version to buy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There is no cross-compatibility of save files between 3DS and Wii U games. This is the case for all games at this time.

Comment: That's a shame. I had hoped I could take the easy Way Forward...

Comment: uuuuuhhhh. Ouch. :)

Comment: Now I'm extra excited for the NX 